# Cannot Run API because of TLS Context

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I'm trying to run my api but it is giving me this error:

```
TlsContext cannot be configured with protocol HTTP, when using tls:context you must set attribute protocol="HTTPS"
```

My current configuration for the TLS is this one :

```
<tls:context name="TLS_Context" doc:name="TLS Context" doc:id="6d944d35-5bda-4e75-af03-de1fd3bebf39"  >
        <tls:trust-store insecure="true" />
        <tls:key-store path="${secure::http.tls.cert}" keyPassword="${secure::http.tls.key}" password="${secure::http.tls.key}" />
    
    </tls:context>
```

Comment: If you are using TLS then you should HTTPS as your protocol. that is what the error you are getting.

Comment: You should share the connector configuration also, not just the TLS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTTP requester or listener if you want to use HTTPS you need to specify it in the connector configuration as the protocol with the `protocol` attribute. Without setting the protocol to HTTPS the default is HTTP, which is contradictory with having a TLS context defined. That's the cause of the error.

Example:

```xml
<http:request-config name="reqConfig" ...>
  <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" ...>
    <tls:context>
      ...
    </tls:context>
  </http:request-connection>
</http:requester-config>
```